# Seconds on Countdown timer android not accurate

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

My countdown timer counts the difference between end_time and current_time in HH:mm:ss format. I noticed that whenever the timer starts to display, the seconds are always rounded off, meaning it will always start to count itself down from HH:59 onwards. Is there a way to make the seconds to show exactly the correct seconds remaining?

Comment: what do you mean with ' exactly the correct seconds remaining?'

Comment: @oblivion For example: End time: 23:00:00 Current time: 22:30:30 Current time is dynamic. When I view the countdown timer, it should show or start at 00:30:30 but when it starts it will show either 00:30:59 or 00:29:59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom `CountDownTimer` for this purpose. say for example:

```
    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
  public MyCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long interval) {
  super(millisInFuture, interval);
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish() {
    my_textview.setText("Time's up!");     
  }

  @Override
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    my_textview.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);   //Shows no. of seconds left
    //Uses a textview to update status                                                        
  }
}
```

And inside of your Activity, you can call the timer as:

```
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(millisInFuture, interval);
//In this case
//CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(50000, 1000);
```

Here `millisInFuture` is the "time left for your particular time interval" in milliseconds when you start the timer. Let's say time left is 50 sec in this case. Then this value will be `50000`

`interval` is the time in milliseconds in which you want to provide update. (i.e if you use 1000 as interval, the timer will update you every 1 second)

So in this case,

```
onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
```

is called every one second which gives you time left for the countdown timer in milliseconds.i.e. millisUntilFinished parameter gives you 49000 (i.e. 49 seconds left) when called for the first time and so on.

When the timer has finished countdown, onfinish() is called.

You can show this information in any way. I've simply shown it in a TextView.

The only step left for you is to actually start the countdown timer. countDownTimer.start();

And as you **did not** want to start it from , say `59` , you can increment the value with `one` every time you set the text.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the info! I found out the reason why. My time was not formatted properly including the seconds that's why it won't read the exact seconds remaining. My bad

Comment: @fmpsagara What are the odds that you remember how you fixed the format? :)
Im facing the same issue today.